# Vue Webpack Progress Plugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm still learning Vue and not confident and have an error that I'm unable to solve by reading the doc's and other posts. Any guidance would be much appreciated...

Project is a Vue2 app with Vuetify...

```
Vue version 2.7.14
npm version 8.15.0
Vue cli 4.5.13
node version v14.18.0
Vuetify 2.6.12
```

The error is....

```
ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf
```

My `package.json` dev dependencies are

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "~7.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "~7.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "~7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "~7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "6.0.3",
    "cross-env": "~5.2",
    "css-loader": "5.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "~1.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "~3.2",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^10",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-avatar-cropper": "^5.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.4.6",
    "vue-loader": "~15.6",
    "vue-style-loader": "~4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.8",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.2",
    "webpack": "~4.29",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-now-ui-kit-pro-angular/issues/6#issuecomment-461227288) that one could be solved by doing

```
yarn add -D webpack@4.24.0
```

or its `npm/pnpm/bun` equivalent.

You can also replace your `~4.29` with that specific number and reinstall your packages again (maybe wipe the `node_modules` + clean the cache).

Comment: I changed the version and it worked perfectly